# Why My Code doesn't support Co-variant Interface?

Tags: c#, dynamic, .net-4.0, covariance

According To reflector , ExpandoObject Does implemenet  `IDictionary<string, object>`

[image]

How ever I have this code which i dont understand why Does Interface co-variance doesn't work here

[image]

From what Ive read  -  it does suppose to work :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three things wrong here:

- [`IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx) is invariant in both its type parameters
- Generic variance doesn't work across value types (`int` here)
- If it *were* covariant, you'd be trying to use it the wrong way round: you're actually trying to use *contravariance*

You should ignore the `dynamic` part here - it's a red herring. Try working out some code you'd *expect* to work that doesn't use `dynamic`. Here's an example of why `IDictionary<,>` is invariant:

```
// Suppose it were covariant in value...
Dictionary<string, string> stringToString = new Dictionary<string, string>();
IDictionary<string, object> stringToObject = stringToString;
stringToObject["foo"] = new MemoryStream();
string value = stringToString["foo"]; // Um?

// Suppose it were contravariant in value...
Dictionary<string, object> stringToObject = new Dictionary<string, object>();
IDictionary<string, string> stringToString = stringToString;
stringToObject["foo"] = new MemoryStream();
string value = stringToString["foo"]; // Um?
```

Comment: yeah it is Contravariant. But I  thought ( from your book also which I have) - That Generic Interface does support Covariant. Generic Class Doesnt... no?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: No, it's not contravariant. Look at the docs I've linked to: it's just `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`. No `in`, no `out`.

Comment: An interface only supports variance if that variance is safe. And `IDictionary<,>` uses `TValue` in both input and output positions, so it can't be variant.

Comment: @CodeInChaos when you mean safe  - its about in out ?

Comment: You can only mark a type parameter as `in` if it is never used in an `out` position, and you can only mark it as `out` if it is never used in an `in` position. Since dictionary uses `TValue` in both positions, it must be invariant.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: My answer shows why the compiler *wouldn't let you* mark `TValue` as being either covariant or contravariant. It would violate type safety.

Comment: @jon CAn't i make my own Covariant interface like `IDictionary<object, object >` ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Not that allows you to both add items to it and take them out again, no... look through my two examples of bad things that could happen if it *were* contravariant.

Answer (score 1):

1. `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>` does not support any variance.
   Imagine what would happen if you could convert `IDictionary<string,object>` to `IDictionary<string,int>`:
   Your interface now *guarantees* that every value it returns is an `int`. But since you can add arbitrary objects to it, it can't actually ensure that guarantee.
2. Even interfaces which support variance, only support it between reference types. `int` is no reference type.
3. This issue is unrelated to dynamic. You can't convert a class that only implements `IDictionary<string,object>` to `IDictionary<string,int>`. No matter if you use static casting or dynamic. It simply doesn't implement that interface.